# How to pass string parameters into ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I hard code in the value I want to pass like this, it works and data is being returned correctly:

```
<!-- This works! --> 
ng-click="LSCC.getCrawlResults(4661224)"
```

However, when I try to save a value from a text box and pass that into my ng-click, I am getting errors.

```
<!-- This doesn't work! -->
<input class="form-control" name="retailerID" ng-model"x">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="LSCC.getCrawlResults('x')">Load</button>
```

I have tried passing parameters in a variety of different ways, but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`x` is assign wrong in `ng-model`, and I guess it's necessary to remove the quotes.

```
<input class="form-control" name="retailerID" ng-model="x">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="LSCC.getCrawlResults(x)">Load</button>
```

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting this message: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'undefined' to data type int."
OUTPUT

Answer (score 1):

Where is your ng-click function defined? In a controller? If so I would just attach everything to $scope and access the ng-model using $scope.x instead of trying to pass it in since that is giving you trouble

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, I forgot an '=' sign.

```
ng-model"x"  <!-- No '=' sign -->
```